# Show that vectors u x w = 0 ( Linear Algebra )

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations

Let $u, v_1$ and $v_2$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that fulfills
$$u \times v_1 =  u \times v_2 = 0.$$

Assume that $w \in \text{Span}(v_1, v_2).$
Show that $$u \times w = 0.$$

I have figured out that the vector $u$ most probably is $0$, ( but I don't know how to show it step by step, I just thought logically, can somebody please help? )

Comment: Hint: if $w\in Span(v_1,v_2)$, then you can write $w=a_1 v_1+a_2 v_2$ where $a_1,a_2\in \Bbb R$. Then what can you say about $u\times w$?

Comment: The problem says we’re in $\Bbb{R}^n$, but if we’re using cross products, doesn’t $n=3$?

Comment: "I have figured out that the vector $\mathbf{u}$ most probably is $\mathbf{0}$" -- no, not at all, it doesn't have to be the zero vector.

Comment: Oh ok, is it in the exact same direction then?